# How to put post title in a table of two columns

Tags: css, xml, blogger

I want to put the post title inside table of 2 columns.

### for example:

```
-------------------------------
post tile 1   |  post title 2
-------------------------------
post title 3  |  post title 4
-------------------------------
post title 5  |  post title 6
```

I am able to print post title but how to put everything inside table and columns.

This is the code i have written so far. 
PS: I don't have much knowledge about blogger theme development

### code:

```
<b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='yes'>
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>

    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
       <b:include name='allposts'/>
    </b:includable>

    <b:includable id='allposts'>
        <b:loop var='thisPost' values='data:posts'>
            <h2>
                <a expr:href='data:thisPost.url'>   <data:thisPost.title/></a>
            </h2>
        </b:loop>
    </b:includable>

</b:widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to create a container element around titles and use CSS `display flex` to layout the table

```
<b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='yes'>
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>

    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
        <b:include name='allposts'/>
    </b:includable>

    <b:includable id='allposts'>
        <div class="container">
            <b:loop var='thisPost' values='data:posts'>
                <h2>
                    <a expr:href='data:thisPost.url'><data:thisPost.title/></a>
                </h2>
            </b:loop>
        </div>
    </b:includable>

</b:widget>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
h2 {
   flex: 1 0 45%;
}
```

**The result**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 h2 {
  flex: 1 0 45%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
     <h2><a href='#'>foo</a></h2>
 
</div>
```

Comment: not working sir. But if i change container to display:flex and h2 display:table-cell than it works. but it doesnt break in new row after 2 columns

Comment: Ok, Because you are using border, decrease h2 width or set an initial one. see me answer update.